# Calculating time complexity for finding first 'n' prime numbers

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

The algorithm for finding first 'n' prime numbers is:

```
while (number <= n) {
  boolean isPrime = true; 
  for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= (int)(Math.sqrt(number)); divisor++) {
    if (number % divisor == 0) {
      isPrime = false;      
      break;
    }
  }
  if(isPrime) 
    System.out.print(number + " ");
}
```

The book, "Introduction to java programming", calculates big-O for this algorithm as:

Since it takes √i steps in the `for` loop to check whether number i is prime, the algorithm takes √2 + √3 + √4 + ... + √n steps to find all the prime numbers less than or equal to n.

Observe that,

√2 + √3 + √4 + ... + √n <= n√n

Therefore, the time complexity for this algorithm is O(n√n).

**Que:**

**1.** He says, "it takes √i steps in the `for` loop to check whether number i is prime".

Don't you think it should be (√i-1) steps.

**2.** Please explain how

√2 + √3 + √4 + ... + √n <= n√n

(I know the relationship holds if you just replace 'n' with a random number. I need explanation)

Comment: Its not really relevant whether it takes sqrt(i) or sqrt(i)-1 steps, thats just a constant factor. If you sum up n constant factors, you'd have all the sqare roots -n, and `O(n*log(n))` is the same as `O(n*log(n) - n)`, as you only need to look at the highest term.

Comment: for your first answer the complexity √i-1 is for finding if number is prime or not. but to find all number till n i will take n√n as n times the loop will go n times and each time it will take √i-1 to check wheather that number is prime or not so overall will be n√n. i hope i answered your doubt

Comment: that's wrong, you need to keep two counters to print the first n numbers. the 100th prime is 541 for example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Complexity-wise, subtracting 1 has no effect (and this is an informal introduction).
   (It's actually `floor(√n) - 1`.)
2. You have n - 1 terms.
   Adding √n n - 1 times:

   √n + √n + √n + ... + √n = (n-1)√n <= n√n

and since √2, √3, √4, ... are all less than √n, it follows that

```
√2 + √3 + √4 + ... + √n <= √n + √n + √n + ... + √n <= n√n
```

Comment: A Google interviewer gave me this exactly question, and he said that n√n can't be the right answer since the outer loop doesn't go to simply n. That is: if we need to print the first n prime number, than the outer loop will be of course Greater than n. Example print first 100 prime, the 100th prime is 541, that is Greater than n. How can we solve this?

Comment: There's some confusion here (I didn't spot it at first). The question asks about the first `n` primes, but the (broken) code and the book quotation in the question are concerned with the primes `<= n`. I guess the first `n` primes would be `O(p(n) * √p(n))`, where `p(n)` is the n:th prime.

Answer (score 1):

### answer 2 :

for 0 < i <= n we have i <= n, therefore √i <= √n, so the sum of √i for i between 1 and n <= the sum of √n between 1 and n which √n + √n ... + √n, n times

Comment: "the sum of √n between 1 and n is n√n." Explain this please

Comment: n times: sqrt(n) + ... + sqrt(n) = n*sqrt(n). Just like 5 times: 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 5*4 = 20

Answer (score 0):

(note this not a complete answer its just to addup to @molbdnilo answer)

consider this:

`1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = n * (n+1) / 2`   --> the time complexity is `O(n*(n+1)/2) ==  O(n^2)`  eventhough `(n * (n+1) / 2) <= (n^2)`

now consider above with what @molbdnilo explained;

> and since √2, √3, √4, ... are all less than √n, it follows that
>
> √2 + √3 + √4 + ... + √n <= √n + √n + √n + ... + √n <= n√n

hope it clears some doubts off